# reload activity without close app in android

Tags: android

I have fragment inside activity I want to refresh the page by menu how I can do it

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   switch (item.getItemId()) {

       case R.id.item_delete:

           // refrash page
           if(db.getAllDataBuyit().size()>0) {
               db.RemoveBuy_AllItem();
               startActivity(getIntent());
           }

           return true;

       default:

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Instead of reload activity better to reload data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can do  startActivity after finish;

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.item_delete:

        // refrash page
        if(db.getAllDataBuyit().size()>0) {
            db.RemoveBuy_AllItem();
            /////////////////////////
             finish();
             startActivity(getIntent());
           /////////////////////////
        }
        return true;
    default:
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Please provide some description as to why your proposed code solves the original problem.

Comment: If you finish and again open launcher activity its takes time and your screen has been the blink or show blank screen its like your app is stopped. getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName()) is use for open a launcher activity without bliking or not showing blank screen while finish activity.